How to make card layout above the banner to ovelap
I need to make the design in tailwind. Check the below outline references,Please help me. Need to build same design. I have used
<div class=“mx-auto max-w-full p-4”>

<img src=“”>
</div>
<div class=“max-w-md md:max-w-xl lg:max-w-7xl xl:max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto relative -top-[8em] z-10”>
<div class=“rounded-lg shadow-md py-8 md:py-16 text-center bg-white”>
<input type=“text”>
</div>
</div>


But its shows more top and the mobile is not responsive. Image part is cut more portion.


Add margin-top in negative like margin-top: -20px.

I used that it was working only maximum -mt-6

Try -translate-y-[20px]

@MuhammedFayaz Predefined would be till  -mt-6 only, you can add more by adding custom properties in tailwind.config file.

I thought any other solution rather than margin top

<div class="h-[50vh]">

<img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" class="w-full h-full object-cover object-center">
</div>
 
<div class="text-center -mt-5">
<input class="border border-black/30 rounded-md px-5 py-2 max-w-[80%] mx-auto w-full " type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>

